# How to run XDebug and Zend side by side?

Tags: netbeans, debugging, xdebug, zend-optimizer

I am using a PHP shopping cart which requires me to use Zend Optimizer.

I am using Netbeans as the IDE, and it requires Xdebug, but that's incompatible with Zend.

These are the lines in my php.ini

```
zend_extension_ts =
"D:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\ZendExtensionManager.dll"
zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts =
"D:\xampp\php\zendOptimizer\lib\Optimizer"

;zend_extension_ts="./php/ext/php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.2.dll"   **<< Xdebug**
```

Whenever I enable Xdebug, my shopping cart gives an error and it does not work.

Is there a way to solve this issue or use another Debugger with Netbeans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot use them side by side. You can choose not to specify the debugger in NetBeans and do the old-fashion print_r-style debugging.

Comment: This is my understanding as well. I don't really see why one would need Zend Optimizer for a shopping cart, esp. when there are many alternatives I imagine

Comment: I think he's using ViArt: http://www.viart.com/is_it_possible_to_install_viart_shopping_cart_without_zend_optimizer.html